# Specify socket send buffer size when performing HTTP POST request

Tags: javascript, sockets, http

Some background: I am working with legacy code, and am attempting to upload a binary file (~2MB) to an embedded microhttpd web server via an HTTP form (POST request). Lately I've noticed that the upload speed from Windows 10 machines is significantly slower than from non-Windows 10 machines: the upload will send a handful of bytes at a time (about 6-7 chunks of ~1500 bytes each) and will then pause, sometimes for 30-60 seconds, before sending another handful of bytes. The decrease in speed caused by this issue renders the whole upload process unusable.

I performed some debugging on the embedded server and found that it was indeed waiting for more data to come in on the socket created for the POST request, and that for some reason this data was not being sent by the client machine. After some analysis in Wireshark on Win10 vs non-Win10 traffic, the messages I am seeing appear to tally up with the issue described by Microsoft here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/823764/slow-performance-occurs-when-you-copy-data-to-a-tcp-server-by-using-a.

Specifically, I am seeing that in the case of Windows 10, the first TCP packet sent to the embedded web server is indeed *"a single send call [that] fills the whole underlying socket send buffer"*, as per the Microsoft article. This does not appear to be the case for non-Windows 10 machines. Hence, I need to be able to set up my sockets so that the web client does not send so much data as to fill up the receive buffer in one packet.

Unfortunately, major modifications to the web server itself (aside from little config tweaks) are out of the question, since the legacy code I'm working with is notoriously coupled and unstable. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to specify socket settings via JavaScript, if this is possible. I'm currently using the JQuery Form plugin, which operates on top of XMLHttpRequests. Since I have complete control over both the JavaScript page and the embedded web backend, I can hard-code the socket buffer sizes appropriately in both cases.

Is there a way to tweak low-level socket settings like this from JavaScript? If not, would there be another workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can do the TCP stack specific tuning you need from inside Javascript running inside a browser on the client side. It simply does not allow this kind of access.